# Display relative date just for today, with "today" as prefix

Tags: date

I am trying to prefix today's (blog)posts with "Today". So that it would read:

> Today, January 12, 2015

From tomorrow on the prefix should not be displayed anymore. I want to achieve an eyecachting effect for the latests posts like that.

I have looked into EE's relative dates but nothing outputs exactly what I need and I don't know how to stop it after today either.

Has anybody achieved this in the past. Seems to be a pretty basic thing actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
{if '{entry_date format="%Y%m%d"}' == '{current_time format="%Y%m%d"}'}Today, {/if}{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
```